# what tool searches for /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)?

Tags: http, intrusion-detection

In my web server logs I get a lot of these:
[error] [client x.x.x.x] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)

I know it's just a failed request and I don't have to worry abut it too much. In the past I have tried searching for the actual script or tool that does this. It must be pretty commonly available judging from the number of occurences of this request. I found different tips on how to deal with the message, but I'm interested in looking at this tool/script itself and I never found its name or location mentioned.

---

My question ends here. A bit more background: Today I noticed one of the clients doing this request is an IP of another server of mine, quite important, actually, because it's my server virtualization host. I suspect intrusion. That's why I want to look at this script - so I can analyze what it does and how to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [has my server been hacked w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind](https://serverfault.com/questions/281286/has-my-server-been-hacked-w00tw00t-at-isc-sans-dfind)

Answer (score 4):

Check the information at: https://isc.sans.edu/diary/w00tw00t/900

> It's a web vulnerability scanner that has this fingerprint. Find and use it at your own risk. We at the *Internet Storm Center* distance ourselves from this tool that is labeled by at least one security company as a hacker tool.